# What Is Best & Effective Algorithm To Reverse A String?

Tags: python

I need a simple and effective algorithm to reverse a string (for example: WelCome to emoCleW ).

I tried a loop:

```
s=input("Enter String To Be Reversed:")
    for i in range(len(s)+1,-1,-1):
        print(str1[0:i])
```

but this didn't work for me

Comment: Different ways of [Reversing a String](https://www.journaldev.com/23647/python-reverse-string). You can see the execution time of each method at the end of the article.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
s=input("Enter String To Be Reversed:")
print(s[::-1])
```

Comment: Why would this be downvoted?

Comment: I'm sorry, I downvoted this and forgot to give an explanation. There's nothing wrong with your answer, but I'm just not sure it adds anything to the more than two dozen answers on the duplicate question linked above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python). Does that make sense?